# AngularJS how to change pagination while search

Tags: php, html, angularjs, pagination

I have used ng-table for my table which works well for pagination, sorting. and I have used ng-model for filtering table data (in short search).
My problem is when I do search it is searching but suppose the word I am searching is at page 3 so it not shows anything till I do not do show all records (till I do not remove pagination). I want to remove pagination  automatically  while search or anything so that the record will come on first page.

Help me, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you provide the a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), showing the efforts of your research?

Comment: Do you use filter for search? look at this example: http://ng-table.com/#/

Comment: @FirasRassas Your link showing nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are currently using pagination in client side data.the better approach is to use the searching in server side return result using limit and offset.

Comment: but it will not able to do me instant search. i want something that shows record when I type in textox

Comment: call the api on ng-change event.

Comment: thank you for the keyword ng-change. solved my problem

Comment: May I get your email id for further assistance.